# D3.js coloring curved stacked area graph wrong

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js, stacked-area-chart

I am trying to create a stacked area graph with D3.js and but it colors the graph wrong:

[image: wrong coloring]

The marked red and gold areas should be colored in purple like in this next picture:

[image: correct coloring]

Is is with identical data but from another library. The gold and red coloring has value 0 in May and June.

This is how I draw and color my Graph:

```
const stackedData = d3.stack()
        .keys(keys)(data.data);

const color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
        .domain(keys)
        .range(data.lineColors);

const area = d3.area()
        .x((d: any) => {
            return x(new Date(d.data['period']))!;
        })
        .y0((d: any) => y(d[0])!)
        .y1((d: any) => y(d[1])!)
        .curve(d3.curveNatural);
svg.selectAll('#chart')
        .data(stackedData)
        .enter()
        .append('path')
        .attr('d', (d: any) => area(d))
        .style('fill', (d: any) => {
            return color(d.key) as string;
        });
```

Comment: When you say 'The gold and red coloring has value 0 in May and June' can you expain more because your first graph shows non zero values in May *and* June

Comment: Likely an artifact of the curve you are using and the ordering of the areas resulting in the result you are seeing. Try using no curve to see if the data is plotted correctly, if so, there may be a different curve that gets the results you want (or a different ordering of the areas) - though if your data is dynamic, then a given curve may produce odd artifacts depending on the current data.

Comment: @AndrewReid the chart was displayed correctly without a curve and your guess was correct, I fixed it with a different arrangement of the areas. And for dynamic data, I now draw each area separately rather than all at once so that the top layer is "above the others".
I think the problem was that d3 draws the lines and then colors the areas in between in the same order as before the point. In this example, there should be only one area after the point. But because of the curved lines, there were still 3 areas colored as before may.